# Polynomial multiplication with complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm looking for the step-by-step for how to multiply the following problem on Khan Academy, because I'm getting a different answer.

$$x(x+3i)(x-2i)$$

I tried distributing the $x$ over both expressions and then multiplied the two expressions together for the result:$$ x^4 -2x^3i + 3x^3i - 6x^2i^2 \implies x^4 - x^3i + 6x^2$$

How should I do?

Comment: You should only have distributed x over one of the expressions. What you did isn't quite how multiplication works :)

Comment: "*I tried distributing the $x$ over* **both** *expressions*"  Why both of them?  $a\times b\times c = a\times (b\times c) = (a\times b) \times c = b\times (a\times c) \neq (a\times b) \times (a\times c)$

Comment: The answer seems to have an extra power of $x$ in all its terms.

Comment: if you wanted to calculate $2\times 3 \times 5$, would you multiply the $2$ by $3$, and then again by $5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributing the monomial $x$ *last* makes work much, much easier.

\begin{align}
x(x+3i)(x-2i)&=x(x^2+ix-6i^2)\\
&=x(x^2+ix+6)\\
&=x^3+ix^2+6x
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$x(x+3i)(x-2i)$

$(x^2+3xi)(x-2i)$

$x^3-2x^2i+3x^2i-6xi^2$

$x^3+x^2i+6x$